# New references won't work because old records Rails Activerecord Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the table trucks and the table checklist.
Originally I only have checklist table and you put the name of the truck with a string.
Now I create the table trucks and I run this command

`rails g migration AddTruckToChecklists truck:references`

later add belongs_to, check the params, show, new, etc.
In local works perfect, in the checklist you select the truck from the table

The problem is that when submit the changes to Heroku I have this error

`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  column "truck_id" contains null values`

I think the problem is the tablee checklist has old values now with a new column (truck_id) and the value is null or something. In local I don't have the problem because I don't have old records in the database.

How can I put a value or let to the system have the old record without a value in the references or all with the same value or any other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to change the default null: false to null:true in the migrations to make it work.
I don't know the consecuentes of that.

```
def change
    add_reference :checklists, :truck, null: true, foreign_key: true
end
```